# How do I reverse a hex string?

Tags: rust, reverse, public-key, secp256k1

Given a hex string, such as `"d59c168e05df4757"`, how can I reverse the bytes of this string, so as to read `[57, 47, df, 05, 8e, 16, 9c, d5]`?

Using the `as_bytes()` method converts each individual character into a byte value, rather than the two-character hex representation.

From bytes representation I have tried the following without success:

```
let bytes = vec![213, 156, 22, 142, 5, 223, 71, 87];
let bytes_reversed = bytes.iter().rev();
println!("Bytes reversed: {:x?}", bytes_reversed);
//Prints: Bytes reversed: Rev { iter: Iter([d5, 9c, 16, 8e, 5, df, 47, 57]) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question - the following approach works to reverse the bytes of a hex string:

1. Convert hex string to bytes
2. Create a new vector
3. Use `iter().rev()` in a `for` loop and `push` each iteration into the new vector

Example code below, using parse_hex function defined in answer to this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201698/convert-string-of-hex-into-vector-of-bytes):

```
let hex_string: String = String::from("d59c168e05df4757");
let string_to_bytes = parse_hex(&hex_string);
println!("Hex string as bytes: {:?}", string_to_bytes); //Prints: [213, 156, 22, 142, 5, 223, 71, 87]
let mut bytes_reversed = Vec::new();
    for i in string_to_bytes.iter().rev() {
        bytes_reversed.push(i);
    }
println!("Bytes reversed: {:x?}", bytes_reversed); //Prints: [57, 47, df, 5, 8e, 16, 9c, d5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be solved using only string operations to get a `Vec` with the reversed hex strings `["57", "47", "df", "05", "8e", "16", "9c", "d5"]` 
 or as reversed `String` `"5747df058e169cd5"`:

```
let hex = "d59c168e05df4757"
    .chars()
    .collect::<Vec<char>>()
    .chunks(2)
    .map(|c2| c2.iter().collect::<String>())
    .rev()
    .collect::<Vec<String>>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=c35dfba4a8b252dd6b403e5e49bef312)